# Send midi events to other MIDI applications with Javasound

Tags: java, midi, javasound

I want to control Software Synthetizers from a java application. Up to know I can send midi events to the default JVM Midi synthetizer, but I can't send these events to other Midi application from my Java program. I wonder how I can tell Javasound to send midi events to applications running on the same computer (Ableton Live, Arturia Synths, etc).

When invoking `MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo()`, it lists

> Software MIDI Synthesizer | Gervill | OpenJDK | 1.0
>
> Software sequencer | Real Time Sequencer | Oracle Corporation | Version 1.0

The target synthetizers are usually able to detect that software running on the same computer are able to send events. My java app is not listed in the "Midi devices" sections where all possible controllers usually appear.

I think I could plug a hardware midi port to which my java app could send events, but I would like to perform app-to-app communication.

[image]

Comment: I sympathize because I might want to do something like that - e.g. VST - to this day there is a JavaVST but all it gives me is a big Zero. Now I have to pack it to a .mid file. The most important thing is for your java program to see that application - but the other way you are doing is theoretically equivalent. You might get some inspiration from other languages.

Comment: You might have some luck with virtual cables as this guy in C++ - If you are able to make a "virtual cable" in java and connect it with no extra party stuff I might look into it

Comment: Thanks! http://jvstwrapper.sourceforge.net/ seems to be a serious framework for VST under Java. Did you try it? Anyway, I presume that one way to connect my app to other application is to let my app emit midi events to the physicial midi device and have the "other" applications (arturia etc) listen to this physical port. But this is cumbersome for app to app communication!